# How to bring alert dialog when user clicks on notification?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to give user an alert dialog when alarm notification of calendar is clicked by the user,How to bring alert dialog when user clicks on notification? My question is where to give alert dialog? Either in Alarmservice? or the Class extending AlarmReceiver that extends BroadCastReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing would be to call a new activity from your BroadcastReceiver.
There you can do whatever you want.

EDIT: This is what I mean:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Now that you're calling a new activity - use it as usual... Add your AlertDialog and show it to the user

Comment: But if i use alertDialog there, i get following error: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

Comment: You probably didn't understand what I meant... I'll edit my response

Comment: Hi, It is showing error in manifest.xml. I get following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver android.todoapplication.AlarmReceiver: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.todoapplication/android.todoapplication.Alert}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Make sure you've added the Alert activity declaration to your AndroidManifest.xml...

Answer (score 0):

Just create an activity and when you register it in your manifest add this tag.
Have your broadcast receiver onReceiver() method launch it.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Also add

```
excludeFromRecents=true or else
```

so this way it wont show up in recent.

Comment: As i have done this before and just launched an activity in my broadcast receiver's onReceiver()